# How to solve this Ruby error message?

Tags: ruby

I want to run a Ruby script (https://github.com/jjyg/rbircd) but I get the below error message:

```
root@li140-48:~/rbircd# ruby -r ircd.rb -e 'Ircd.run("ircd.conf", "irc_log.txt")'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- ircd.rb (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
```

I'm not sure what this is telling me since I'm quite new to Ruby, but to me it looked like it is complaining that there is no such file as `ircd.rb` but this file is there.

Am I misunderstanding the error message it's giving?

```
ls rbircd/
  README
  crypto.rb
  ircd.conf
  ircd.rb   
  ircd_commands.rb
  oper_mkpass.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do as below :

```bsh
[arup@Ruby]$ cat > so/a.rb
class Foo
  def foo
    12
  end
end
^C
[arup@Ruby]$ cat so/a.rb
class Foo
  def foo
    12
  end
end
[arup@Ruby]$ ruby -ra -e "puts Foo.new.foo"
 ..'require': cannot load such file -- a (LoadError)
[arup@Ruby]$ ruby -Iso -e 'p $LOAD_PATH.first'
"/home/arup/Ruby/so"
[arup@Ruby]$ ruby -Iso -e "puts Foo.new.foo"
-e:1:in '<main>': uninitialized constant Foo (NameError)
[arup@Ruby]$ ruby -Iso -ra -e "puts Foo.new.foo"
12
```

Use `ruby -h` to read about below :

- `-rlibrary` - require the library before executing your script
- `-Idirectory` - specify $LOAD_PATH directory (may be used more than once)

Answer (score 0):

### Qualify Your Library Path

You need to use a full or relative path with the `-r` flag. For example, the following should include your ircd.rb library:

```
ruby -r ./ircd.rb -e 'Ircd.run("ircd.conf", "irc_log.txt")'
```